# Pop Up Menu Button

Tags: c#, button

I wish to make that a popup menu will appear out of a button on a **left key** button press in C#.

(Like the reboot/logout menu in Windows 10 which appears after you press the circular button which you can see in the example picture.)

All I've found is related to Menustrip/Contextstrip, however I don't want a strip nor a right key contextstrip; i just want a menu out of a button.

[image: Pop up menu Example]

Comment: any reason you don't want t context menu strip?  you can make one appear on a button click that looks similar if not the same as the example you gave.  Also what are you writing this in, wpf or win forms? or something else.

Comment: but is it a **left click** ?

Comment: yes.  You create the context menu strip and set it to visible on click.  Its actually rather easy.

Comment: Ok , so how i can do that ?

Comment: It's working now , Thanks :)

Comment: lol just noticed your message from 23 hours ago and was just about to respond.  You never said whether you were using wpf or wind forms :) didn't know how to answer.